# Bootstrap button alignment with Navbar list menu?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a small website and I'm stuck with the button alignment problem. I have a navbar list menu and I'd like to add a transparent Logout button near to them just in shape of another menu element, however, I couldn't be successful so far.

Here's a Bootply link you could see the problem; http://www.bootply.com/OXfRkJHEHs

I'd be grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                       <li>
                        <a style="color:#900C3F" href="index.php">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a style="color:#900C3F" href="festival.php">Festival</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>

                        <a style="color:#900C3F" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
                    </li>  
                    <li>
                        <a style="color:#900C3F" href="map.php">Map</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Logout" class="btn element" style="color:#900C3F; background-color: transparent; margin-top:7px" href="Logout.php">

                  </li> 
         </ul></div>


            <div id="push"></div>


</form>
```